# Getting 404 error when accessing php page in apache in a simple php application?

Tags: php, apache, php-5.3, apache2.2

I have created a simple php file `sample.php` under `/var/www/project/dummy/test/sample.php`

Here is the `httpd.conf`

```
 Listen 8080
    <VirtualHost *:8080>
            ServerName example.com
            DocumentRoot "/var/www/projects/dummy/test"
            <Directory "/var/www/projects/dummy/test">
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from all
            </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Here is the `sample.php` (just checking if memcache is enabled)

```
<? php

if(class_exists('Memcache')){
  echo "found";
}

?>
```

when I access `localhost:8080/sample.php` or `localhost:8080/test/sample.php`, I get `404 error`. I am unable to figure out what is going wrong.

I am concerned why `localhost` if failing.

To add to that, even `www.example.com/sample.php` is failing.

Thanks for help

P.S: I have mapped ip address in `/etc/hosts` as follows:

`127.0.0.1 example.com www.example.com localhost`

why is `localhost` failing?

Comment: `<? php` should be `<?php` .  Aside from that, make sure that apache is configured to load and run php scripts (mod_php, cgi, etc),  and/or the sample.php file resides in `/var/www/projects/dummy/test/` .  You may also check for `.htaccess` which can override configuration settings due to your `AllowOverride All` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The document root in httpd.conf is `/var/www/projects/dummy/test`, however you said the files were located at `/var/www/project/dummy/test/sample.php`. Note "project" is singular in one and plural in the other. This would cause 404's.

The Apache logs are also a good place to start when debugging 404's. I'm not sure which OS you're running, but on Ubuntu they can be found at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.